# vDos arabic codepage issue

Tags: visual-foxpro

I'm trying to run a legacy code that use (Microsoft FoxPro 2.5 in widows 10) using vdos, the program works but the language broken; its seems that the main language is Arabic, so I try to change the codepage code nothing works.

**Same problem [here](https://vdos.proboards.com/thread/84/running-program-english-arabic-language).**

[image]

[image]

### What I think

---

when I open dos in windows 98 first the codepage be `437`, then when I run the program the codepage change to `711` ; what the program did is use `nlsfunc` to change the language/codepage to `711`.